# Beginner SQL database design, where to place foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing an online uni program and we have just started designing databases. for an assignment we have to build a fairly large student to teacher lesson booking system but I think my concept of where to place foreign keys is off, before I rebuild the whole database can you help advise what is best practice? for example I have 1 entity, "Parent" and another "Address", the address entity is also used for "Student" and "Teacher". Currently I put a 1:1 relationship between "Parent" and "Address", and the Address_Address_ID INT (an auto increment PK from Address) as a FK in Parent. What I think I have realised is that this FK should not be stored in "Parent"?

Would it be correct to make a join/intermediary table eg. "Parent_Has_Address" that has A composite key or should I put the "Parent" PK into "Address" as an FK?

Sorry for the long question, I have tried working this out for hours, and trying to book a tutor online has only led to people asking for money to finish my assignment for me which isnt what I want.

[image]

Comment: With current solution you can say that specific Parent item can have only one Address while one Address row can be used by multiple Parents. It may be ok, but this depends on you business needs in fact. With additional table (which is called association table) you can build relation like one person can have multiple addresses and one address can be used by multiple persons.

Comment: Thank you Adam! so would it be normal practice to have the association table? or to put the Parent_ID into the Address Entity as a FK?

Comment: Yup, both solution are commonly used. If you need `many-to-many` you use association table, if you need `one-to-many`, you use FK. Of course you could also have kind of `one-to-many`, or even `one-to-one` with association table, but there you need to add additional unique indexes.

Comment: For 1:1 relationship you would place FKs in both address and parents tables. But as Adam has already wrote: it all depends on your business requirements.

Comment: @ScottCooper `If you need many-to-many you use association table, if you need one-to-many, you use FK` I would like to comment that an association table also needs FK's setup

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your diagram, and reading the columns, it may be a personal preference, but double labeling your columns does might be overkill.  What I mean is, example, your `Parent` table as its primary key ID `Parent_ID` which is fine.  Now, when you have that ID in any table OTHER than the `Parent` table, you refer to it as `Parent_Parent_ID`.  Some might think its a type-o or wonder why named that way.  In one way, it APPEARS your naming convention for a foreign key is to put its table association in front of the actual PK column name, such as in your `Student_has_Parent` table.

A table typically represents a single "thing", whatever that thing is, has its "ID" as the primary key and only one will exist in that table.

```
Parent -> Parent_ID
Student -> Student_ID
Teacher -> Teacher_ID
```

If you see the "ID" column in any other table that is NOT the same as it's reference, it would be implied it is the foreign key.  The column name itself would indicate where it came from, hence `Parent_ID` originates from the Parent table.  No need to be redundant with `Parent_Parent_ID`

So, for example in your `Student_has_Parent` table. I would just have three columns `Student_has_Parent_ID` (pk to this table), then `Student_ID` and `Parent_ID`.  Since the table is neither `Student` nor `Parent`, it is implied as a foreign key to the respective `Student` and `Parent` tables.

As for the Address table that multiple people may share a same address, I would NOT recommend multiple parent IDs sharing a same address.  Lets take this scenario.  A typical family (not trying to be politically correct).  Mother, Father, Child.  All live at home, yes, they all share the same address.  Child goes off to college and moves into a dorm off-campus.  Multiple students in same off-campus dorm, now they all share same address?  Yes, but now one of the other students moves out of one dorm to another and edit the data.  Did you just move all students from that dorm to another?  Just be careful of such a situation.

Additionally, I have never been fond of prefixing column names with their context such as you have in parent and student such as Parent_FName, Parent_LName vs Student_FName, Student_LName.  I would just have as FirstName and LastName.  The table it is in gives it the context.  And when querying from a given able, you should always use the alias.column in your query when dealing with multiple tables to add clarification and you could rename the final column from that.  For example

```
select
      S.StudentID,
      S.FirstName Student_FirstName,
      S.LastName  Student_LastName,
      P.FirstName Parent_FirstName,
      P.LastName  Parent_LastName
   from
      Student s
         JOIN Student_has_Parent shp
            on s.Student_ID = shp.Student_ID
            JOIN Parent p
               on shp.Parent_id = P.Parent_ID
   where
      [whatever criteria]
```

Notice the explicit ALIAS "S" and "P" for the student and parent tables respectively and qualifying the column names.  The output could show explicitly, but not require the root table to be called as such.

Just my input for you, and good luck moving forward on your project.

Comment: Thanks Drapp, I ended up rebuilding it with better relations and naming convetions. + thanks for the tip on the Alias S. or P.!

Comment: @ScottCooper, on Stack Overflow you say "thanks" by marking an answer as accepted.